# ToListAsync() vs AsDocumentQuery()

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I just read this [section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/performance-tips-query-sdk?tabs=v2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#avoid-recreating-the-iterator-unnecessarily) which shows this example:

```
IDocumentQuery<dynamic> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery(
    UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseName, CollectionName), 
    "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.city = 'Seattle'", 
    new FeedOptions 
    { 
        PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("Washington")
    }).AsDocumentQuery();
while (query.HasMoreResults) 
{
    foreach(Document document in await queryable.ExecuteNextAsync())
    {
        // Iterate through documents
    }
}
```

In our project's codebase, we're doing something like this instead:

```
var invoiceList = await CreateDocumentQuery(companyId).Where(i => i.InvoiceId == invoiceId).ToListAsync();
```

where `CreateDocumentQuery()` returns an `IOrderedQueryable<Invoice>`.

Is it bad to use `ToListAsync()`?
When should I use `ToListAsync()` vs `AsDocumentQuery()`/`ExecuteNextAsync()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AsDocumentQuery` let's you consume the query at your own pace and yield if you need to paginate (returning the Continuation Token).

`ToListAsync` drains the query completely in one go.

It depends on your use case, which pattern fits better. The recommendation that I see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/troubleshoot-query-performance#common-sdk-issues is: " Be sure to drain the query completely."

`ToListAsync` would drain it completely, `AsDocumentQuery` would too as long as you consume it until `HasMoreResults` is `false` (like in your snippet).